# Android: Cursor in MediaStore returns 0 while searching Tracks by Album

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I'm trying to find the list of tracks by album ids which are currently saved on the external memory. After getting the valid album ids I can fetch a list of tracks only if the album has more than 1 track. This is kinda weird by all albums with a single track is returning 0 cursor size where there should be at least one track. If the album has more than 1 tracks a list of tracks is receiving successfully. Here's the code snippet,

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID + "=" + id;
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uri,
                null,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0 AND " + selection,
                null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");
        ArrayList<MediaItem> listOfSongs = new ArrayList<MediaItem>();
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            MediaItem songData = new MediaItem();

            String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String artist = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            String album = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            long duration = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
            String data = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            long albumId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
            long artistId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));
            String composer = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER));

            songData.setTitle(title);
            songData.setAlbum(album);
            songData.setArtist(artist);
            songData.setDuration(duration);
            songData.setPath(data);
            songData.setAlbumId(albumId);
            songData.setArtistId(artistId);
            songData.setComposer(composer);
            listOfSongs.add(songData);
        }
        c.close();
        Log.d("SIZE", "SIZE: " + listOfSongs.size());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used the `c.MoveToFirst()` right before running the while loop. As a result  when the loop starts, the index will move to the next item instead of first. Check my modified version of the code,

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = "";
        // album was requested
        if (is_album) {
            selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID + "=" + id;
        }
        // artist was requested
        else {
            selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID + "=" + id;
        }
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uri,
                null,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0 AND " + selection,
                null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");
        ArrayList<MediaItem> listOfSongs = new ArrayList<MediaItem>();

        if (c == null) {
            // error - log some message
        }
        else if (c.getCount() < 1) {
            // nothing to show  - log some message
        }
        else {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                MediaItem songData = new MediaItem();

                String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String artist = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String album = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                long duration = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
                String data = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                long albumId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                long artistId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));
                String composer = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER));

                songData.setTitle(title);
                songData.setAlbum(album);
                songData.setArtist(artist);
                songData.setDuration(duration);
                songData.setPath(data);
                songData.setAlbumId(albumId);
                songData.setArtistId(artistId);
                songData.setComposer(composer);
                listOfSongs.add(songData);
            }
            c.close();
            Log.d("SIZE", "SIZE: " + listOfSongs.size());
        }
```